# In visual studio 2010, when I open a form in design view - some numbers showing up next to each control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, controls, designer

I keep seeing these odd looking numbers on just one of the forms in my application. Any idea why this appears - this doesn't cause any trouble in running the application, but I need to make some changes in the design and the regular selection borders are not visible.

These may be the tab orders, but couldn't find out how to remove/ hide these.
All help would be appreciated.
Upen

Got the answer guys- in the main vs2010 main menu- go to View--> taborder - click to toggle off or on.

Comment: can you share some screen shot or something, it's really unusual

Comment: I couldnt share a screen shot as I havent the required "reputation" as per stack overflow terms.. Anyways- in the  main menu of vs2010 - click on View--> Taborder will toggle the numbers on or off.